# does deploying a github page from Jekyll have issues with updates?

Tags: github, deployment, jekyll

After I commit and pushed my changes to the files, the last step was to deploy the website,

This is what deploy.yml file look like

```
name: deploy

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
      - main
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

permissions:
  contents: write

jobs:
  deploy:
    # available images: https://github.com/actions/runner-images#available-images
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Checkout ️
      uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Setup Ruby
      uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1
      with:
        ruby-version: '3.2.2'
        bundler-cache: true
    - name: Update _config.yml ⚙️
      uses: fjogeleit/yaml-update-action@v0.13.1
      with:
        commitChange: false
        valueFile: '_config.yml'
        propertyPath: 'giscus.repo'
        value: ${{ github.repository }}
    - name: Install and Build 
      run: |
        pip3 install --upgrade jupyter
        npm install -g mermaid.cli
        npm install -g purgecss
        export JEKYLL_ENV=production
        bundle exec jekyll build --lsi
        purgecss -c purgecss.config.js
    - name: Deploy 
      if: github.event_name != 'pull_request'
      uses: JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action@v4
      with:
        folder: _site
```

I run this command `bin/deploy --user` but I got the following error

```
Error:  Logging at level: debug 
Configuration file: /github/workspace/./_config.yml 
GitHub Pages: github-pages v228 
GitHub Pages: jekyll v3.9.3 
Theme: jekyll-theme-primer 
Theme source: /usr/local/bundle/gems/jekyll-theme-primer-0.6.0 
Requiring: jekyll-github-metadata 
Requiring: jekyll-seo-tag 
Requiring: jekyll-feed 
Requiring: jekyll-sitemap 
Requiring: jemoji 
Requiring: jekyll-coffeescript 
Requiring: jekyll-commonmark-ghpages 
Requiring: jekyll-gist 
Requiring: jekyll-github-metadata 
Requiring: jekyll-paginate 
Requiring: jekyll-relative-links 
Requiring: jekyll-optional-front-matter 
Requiring: jekyll-readme-index 
Requiring: jekyll-default-layout 
Requiring: jekyll-titles-from-headings 
GitHub Metadata: Initializing... 
Source: /github/workspace/. 
Destination: /github/workspace/./_site 
Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental 
Generating... 
EntryFilter: excluded /Gemfile 
EntryFilter: excluded /bin 
Reading: _posts/2018-12-22-distill.md 
Reading: _posts/2020-09-28-twitter.md 
Reading: _posts/2015-05-15-images.md 
Reading: _posts/2023-11-27-code.md 
Reading: _posts/2022-02-01-redirect.md 
Reading: _posts/2015-03-15-formatting-and-links.md 
Reading: _posts/2023-07-12-post-bibliography.md 
Generating: JekyllOptionalFrontMatter::Generator finished in 0.000214953 seconds. 
Generating: JekyllReadmeIndex::Generator finished in 0.00117622 seconds. Jekyll Feed: Generating feed for posts 
Generating: JekyllFeed::Generator finished in 0.000644705 seconds. Generating: Jekyll::JekyllSitemap finished in 0.000918378 seconds. Generating: Jekyll::Paginate::Pagination finished in 3.066e-06 seconds. Generating: JekyllRelativeLinks::Generator finished in 0.000551321 seconds. Generating: JekyllDefaultLayout::Generator finished in 0.000259886 seconds. Generating: JekyllTitlesFromHeadings::Generator finished in 1.6571e-05 seconds. 
Rendering: 404.html 
Pre-Render Hooks: 404.html 
Rendering Liquid: 404.html 
GitHub Metadata: Generating for AyoubAjarra/ayoubajarra.github.io 
GitHub Metadata: Calling @client.pages("AyoubAjarra/ayoubajarra.github.io", {}) 
Rendering Markup: 404.html 
Rendering Layout: 404.html 
Layout source: site github-pages 228 | Error: Liquid syntax error (line 17): Unknown tag 'bibliography'
```

I am not sure what changed with the current jekyll version, the url doesn't appear in girhub/pages, it seems like there's a problem with docker...

Answer (score 0):

In some page you've used `bibliography` as a liquid tag.

```
Error: Liquid syntax error (line 17): Unknown tag 'bibliography'
```